# Creating an ActiveAdmin project with an existing mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a fairly large SQL database that I would like to begin managing with ActiveAdmin/Rails.  Should I try to make an ActiveRecord model for every table in the database, or is there an easier way to accomplish this?  I have a fair amout of experience with Rails but this will be my first time using ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to describe all tables in models. You can try to describe Active Admin without model itself and you'll get error about that. 
More info is here http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html